# SQL exception while creating connection to SQL Server using jdbc

Tags: jdbc, sqlexception

I am getting the following error while creating a connection to SQL Server using jdbc. THe error is :

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver//D-PC//SQLEXPRESS;integratedSecurity=true
Failed to make connection!

```
    import java.sql.Connection; import java.sql.DriverManager; import java.sql.SQLException; import java.sql.Statement;

    /**  *  * @author Jatin  */ public class SQLConnect {
        public Connection sqlcon(Connection conn){
           try{
               Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
           }
           catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           Statement stmt = null;
           try{
               conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver//D-PC//SQLEXPRESS;integratedSecurity=true");
               stmt = conn.createStatement();
               stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE Students");
               System.out.println("Database Created");
           }
           catch(SQLException e){
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           if (conn != null) {      System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");     } else {        System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");   }
            return(conn);
        }
        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Connection con =null;
           SQLConnect sqlcon = new SQLConnect();
           con = sqlcon.sqlcon(con);
        }

}
```

Comment: Read http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms378428%28v=sql.110%29.aspx. Your URL is incorrect. And you of course need to have the SQLServer JDBC driver jar in the classpath.

Comment: You forgot a colon after `sqlserver` the URL should be: `jdbc:sqlserver://D-PC//SQLEXPRESS;integratedSecurity=true`

Comment: Now the error turns out to be this com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host D-PC, named instance sqlexpress failed. Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.

Answer (score 0):

The connection to the host GUNA, named instance sqlexpress failed. Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434. For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:237)

how to resolve this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).